# Can an LTC4311 I2C amplifier be used along with PCA9515A I2C repeater

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, serial

Can the LTC4311 ([click for datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4311fa.pdf)) be used along with the PCA9515A ([click for datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_NXP-Semicon-PCA9515ADP_C129508.pdf)) I2C bus repeater?

EDIT to describe my goal: I am using a RaspberryPi4 with around 1m long cables and the TCA9548 multiplexer with additional two I2C devices on each channel. I've calculated the bus capacitance to be around 350pF in air but the cables are immersed in water. That changes epsilon_r from 1 to over 80 and adds a lot of additional capacitance. The setup is kind of working but unstable and most likely (due to water immersion) out of the bus capacitance specification.

EDIT2: The RPI4 is connected over some jumper/dupont wires to a custom-built PCB with just a TCA9548a 8CH-multiplexer on board that separately switches Channel0 to Channel7. Behind/after each channel comes an around 1m long 30AWG cable (as described above, [please check amazon product link here](https://www.amazon.de/30-AWG-Draht-Farbdraht-Kit-Silikondraht-verschiedenfarbige-60V-Elektronikdraht/dp/B07G712DY4/ref=sr_1_4_sspa?crid=2KORZNV3LTJR&keywords=30%20awg&qid=1642405361&sprefix=30awg%2Caps%2C102&sr=8-4-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExREYyMTcySk5QVzQzJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNDQyNzY5WVVHQjBKUUJCSkdBJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA2MjQ2NTcxRzkwMVdaVERWTzlZJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==)) connected to two more I2C sensors (ADXL345 and ADS1110) on custom PCBs with a capacitance of around 10pF each. The Mux has a max capacitance of around 30pF. The custom PCBs have additional pullups of 10k on each line. The RPI has 1.8k on each line already, speed is 10kHz (tried higher speeds also but should be worse). The mux is powered over 3.3V from the RPI.

EDIT3:
Please see a photo of the setup here:
[image]

Looking at the wiring diagrams:
[image: LTC4311 wiring]
and
[image: PCA9515A wiring]
I don't see why it shouldn't.

Theoretically I also cannot see a difference for the order of putting these two ICs

Comment: I don''t have an exact answer if it will work or not, you have to calculate based on every little detail how these devices work.

Usually, and PCA9515 is no exception, there cannot be two I2C repeaters in series on the same bus, based on how they work internally and actively sense the bus which side pulls low and which does not.

Adding another component on bus that actively senses the bus to accelerate rise time will be just asking for trouble. It will make a difference on which side the accelerator is, as it can only accelerate the side where the accelerator is.

Comment: @Justme thank you. I will most likely only go for the LTC4311 anyways.

Comment: Perhaps if you described what you are actually doing or what actual problems you are trying to solve, we could understand better what to answer. I bet you really want to know something else than "if component X and Y can be used together".

Comment: You’ve got to ask yourself if you really want to run I2C any distance. Make sure your code can cope with bus lockups. If you don’t know about these, then you’re going to find out soon!

Comment: @Justme I have edited my question. I want to compenste bus capacitance due to 1m long wires that are immersed in water. The water adds additional capacitance on the 30AWG wires surrounded by silicone. Conductor core diameter is around 0.25mm, the total diameter is 1.2mm and epsilon_r estimated to be around 3.5.

Comment: @Kartman I'm just aware that bus lockups are a problem with an I2C buffer. To my knowledge it can only happen with the PCA9515 that separates the I2C lines and not with the LTC4311. I've edited my question with more information on my goal.

Comment: Which kind of cable it is? How it is wired? Is there a shield? Twisted pairs? Show the schematics? 350pF total, with host on one end and two muxes on other end of 1m of cable sounds unrealistic. Are you using chips on your PCB or just wired ready-made modules together? Do you enable all mux channels or one channel at a time? How are any of these powered? What I2C speed you are using? How much pull-up currents? What pull-up resistances in which places? What speed you need?

Comment: @Justme I've tried to provide the missing information in my second edit. I bundled the 30AWG wires to 4 wires (GND, VCC, SCL, SDA) using a drilling machine, no shielding. I am just using one mux along with 8custom PCBs (2I2C sensors) behind each channel and 1m per ch annel.

Comment: Maybe you should start another question, as really the question has changed from "can X be used with Y" to "what's wrong with my current I2C design". To be honest, it already sounds like a horrible design, which can't be evaluated until we see some schematics of the boards, scope pictures of signals, etc.

Comment: @MarcoBobinger, you don't need an I2C Buffer to suffer bus lockups. A transient or ground bounce will cause it. Be sure that you can detect it and recover.

Comment: @Justme I have added a photo of the setup, which should give a good idea of the wiring. I wouldn't say that the setup is totally horrible since it works, just unstable, probably due to the capacitance the I2C bus is operated  much outside of the specs. I'll try to nail down the problem further by measuring signals in water (in air they were perfectly fine at 10kHz). I'll also use an LTC4311. As alternative, I check my options for using RS485 or alternatives. Thank you for the hints!

Comment: Twisting wires like that is a sure way to cause crosstalk problems. The 10k pull-ups to 3.3V are also very weak on the cable side of the mux. And I2C bus has no hard limit on capacitance, it is allowed to be run above 400pF by for example lowering the clock frequency which you have done. Are the sensors powered by 5V or 3.3V, do they have pull-ups to which voltage? You need to have oscilloscope pictures of bus signals to know what the issue is and how to fix it. Do you have bypass caps on sensor boards, for instance? Proper design of I2C bus should go many meters with no problems.